# Wordpress: Trying to call get_permalink in widget definition - throws error

Tags: php, wordpress

The commented line below throws an error.

```
class Overall_Travel_Times_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    var $title       = 'Travel Times Widget';
    //var $title_link  = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'delays' ) );
```

How can I access the standard wordpress functionality from inside the widget definition?

Comment: Are you sure `get_page_by_path()` is the right function? What is `delays`?

Comment: @mevius delays is a slug.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: @mevius Not sure, its failing silently as far as the browser is concerned  (I am not a wordpress developer, don't have a clue how to debug the server). Anyway, I put the call in the widget function and its working fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are trying to get the permalink of the page which has slug named as 'delays'? You still facing issue or you have resolved it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, it was outputting parse error "unexpected var"

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)
```

I remove var keyword in front of your variables and it worked:

```
 $title       = 'Travel Times Widget';
 $title_link  = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'delays' ) );
```

So after removing 'var' which you have in front of both variables, your code will work fine. As I tested it provided me the link for the page with the slug I provided.